# Django CSRF validation fails

Tags: django, cookies

I am using django 1.10. I have {% csrf_token %} in my forms where POST is been used. I am using django registration redux for handling the registration process.
While trying to register a new user, I get a 403 error CSRF VERIFICATION FAILED. REASON for failure CSRF cookie not set. CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE is set to false.
These are the middleware classes

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]
```

Registration View

```
class RegistrationView(FormView):
    """
    Base class for user registration views.

    """
    disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
    form_class = REGISTRATION_FORM
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
    success_url = None
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
        dispatch or do other processing.

        """
        if not self.registration_allowed():
            return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
        return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_user = self.register(form)
        success_url = self.get_success_url(new_user)

        # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
        # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
        # tells us which one it is.
        try:
            to, args, kwargs = success_url
        except ValueError:
            return redirect(success_url)
        else:
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)

    def registration_allowed(self):
        """
        Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
        globally or on a per-request basis.

        """
        return True

    def register(self, form):
        """
        Implement user-registration logic here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_success_url(self, user=None):
        """
        Use the new user when constructing success_url.

        """
        return super(RegistrationView, self).get_success_url()
```

template

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Register for an account" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @Alasdair view and template shown

Comment: Does the csrf token appear in the rendered template (e.g. if you click view source in your browser).

Comment: @Alasdair yes it is present over there

Comment: Are you submitting the form using AJAX?

Comment: @Alasdair No not using ajax

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out what the problem is.